# Change non-modifiability of an array by using a structure

Tags: c

From  Kerrek SB's comment on
    [Why can't a modifiable lvalue have an array type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656162/why-cant-a-modifiable-lvalue-have-an-array-type#comment78270790_45656162)

> You can trivially assign arrays by making them members of a struct and then assigning those lvalues.

What does it mean? Does it mean that if a structure has an array member, then the array member can be modifiable? But the following example doesn't work:

I define a struct type with a member being an array

```
typedef struct { int arr[3];} MyType;
```

Then

```
MyType myStruct;
myStruct.arr = (int[]) {3,2,1};
```

and got `error: assignment to expression with array type`.

Comment: For your code, you'd need to use: `MyType myStruct;
myStruct.arr = (MyType) { { 3, 2, 1 } };` or `myStruct.arr = (MyType) { .arr = { 3, 2, 1 } };` to create a compound literal of the structure type, which can then be assigned to the structure as a whole.  You still can't do array assignments, so any assignment to `myStruct.arr` is bogus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it means that if you assign an instance of a `struct` like the one in your example to another `struct` you are effectively assigning arrays.

```
struct Array {
    int array[3];
};

struct Array A;
struct Array B = {{0, 1, 2}}; // by Chris Dodd
// This is valid!
A = B;
```

Comment: and you can initialize `B` with an array initializer declaration like: `struct Array B = {{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 }};`

Comment: @ChrisDodd I was to lazy to do so, so I will borrow yours if you don't mind.

Comment: `A = B;` must be inside a function for it to be valid

Comment: There are sometimes advantages to sticking with the example from the question, where the array size is only 3 — it is simpler to create the compound literal.

Comment: @M.M. why has to be inside a function?

Comment: @Tim because assignments aren't valid at global scope. Only declarations are.