# *x different from x[0] when x is a pointer to an array of undefined dimensions

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I've thought that `a[0]` is equivalent to `*a`, but then I came across this piece of code:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
int (* a)[] = &arr;
printf("%d", (*a)[2]); // compiles
printf("%d", a[0][2]); // errors out
```

There is a pointer to an array of unspecified size. The first expression compiles nicely, yet the second one results in

```
test.c:8:21: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
     printf("%d", a[0][2]);
                     ^
```

The error from Clang is

```
error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'int []'
```

and from MSVC v19.10

```
error C2036: 'int (*)[0]': unknown size
```

---

Why isn't `a[0]` equivalent to `*a`?

Comment: While at this I found a "bug" (EEE anyone) in MSVC. Apparently msvc considers `int (*)[]` to be `int (*)[0]`...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and is that taken from the first indexing?

Comment: @SouravGhosh [nope...](https://godbolt.org/z/MpwuNN)

Comment: D'oh and it is a duplicate :F - I thought I had done thorough search but couldn't find the duplicate except when searching for discussion on the MSVC bug. So I guess this is good to have here then.

Comment: By curiosity, why you do not delete your question being a duplicate in the same way you delete the ones written by other OP ?

Comment: @bruno https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/918959 - those few that I've deleted are such that no one would *actually* find help for their problem by googling them. There are actually *other* close reasons that equally apply to them but they're also low quality duplicates.

Comment: @bruno Likewise I ask you: why can't I see you often casting a close vote...

Comment: But I do close votes, what is the minimal value of often ^^ ? more seriously I do even I do not very like, it is not 'gentle' for the OP (not sure is the right word, my poor English) even needed for stackoverflow quality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 are not strictly equivalent. `a[0]` is exactly equivalent to `*(a + 0)` ([C11 6.5.2.1p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2)).

For `*`, [C11 6.5.3.2p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p2) says that

> 2. The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.

which `int (*)[]` is; the result of dereference `(*a)` is `int []`, which decays to `int *`, which is then indexed with `[2]`, which results in 3.

However `a[0][2]` is equivalent to `(*(a + 0))[2]`, and here the rules of binary `+` operator apply first! [C11 6.5.6p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p2) says that

> **Constraints**
>
> 2. For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, **or one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type** and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding 1.)

`0` has an integer type, and `a` is a pointer, but it is not a pointer to a complete object type, which means it does not match the constraints.

Since this text occurs in the constraints section, a conforming compiler **must** diagnose this as constraint violation. As always, a conforming implementation may still correctly translate an invalid program, but at least GCC seems to reject this outright with an error message.

Comment: Short answer: Function pointers cannot be used in pointer arithmetics.

Comment: @iBug yes I was going to add that too, but it is besides the point.

Comment: @iBug true, but how is that an "answer" here?