# Copy One Struct Member to Another Struct

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm struggling with this syntax: I have a few structs of arrays:

```
struct Msg {
    uint8_t Data[DATA_SIZE];
};

struct Msg Msg_Buff[NUM_MESSAGES], Temp_Buff[NUM_MESSAGES];
```

and want to copy one array from one struct to another.

This:

```
*Temp_Buff[Other_Indx].Data = *Msg_Buff[This_Indx].Data;
```

copies ONLY the first element of the array, not the whole array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `memcpy(Temp_Buff[Other_Index].Data,Msg_Buff[This_Index].Data,sizeof(Msg.Data));`

Comment: You can't assign  to arrays, whether they're normal variables or struct members.

Comment: You _can_ copy whole `struct` with an assignment: `Temp_Buff[Other_Indx] = Msg_Buff[This_Indx];`

Comment: Is `Data` really the only member of the struct, or is this simplified from the real struct definition?

Comment: The `*` with zero offset is the equivalent of `Temp_Buff[Other_Indx].Data[0] = Msg_Buff[This_Indx].Data[0];`, which explains why only the first element is being copied

Comment: I suggest to rephrase the title like this: "How to copy a member of a strruct that is an array into another strruct?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `memcpy` for that if you want to copy only one member.

```
#define DATA_SIZE 100
#define NUM_MESSAGES 200

struct Msg {
    uint8_t Data[DATA_SIZE];
};

struct Msg Msg_Buff[NUM_MESSAGES], Temp_Buff[NUM_MESSAGES];


void copyDataAtIndex(size_t index)
{
    memcpy(Temp_Buff[index].Data, Msg_Buff[index].Data, sizeof(Temp_Buff[index].Data));
}
```

If you want to copy the whole struct - simply assign:

```
void copyStructAtIndex(size_t index)
{
    Temp_Buff[index] = Msg_Buff[index];
}
```

Comment: Follow up: if I want to copy MULTIPLE arrays, but not ALL, from one to another, I need to iterate with a memcpy for each iteration?

Comment: you need to `memcpy` one by one

Answer (score 6):

Largely for [historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45683469/298225), in C arrays cannot be assigned.

If the array is the only member in the structure, you can simply assign the structure instead of the array: `Temp_Buff[Other_Indx] = Msg_Buff[This_Indx];`.

Otherwise, copy the entire array: `memcpy(Temp_Buff[Other_Indx].Data, Msg_Buff[This_Indx].Data, sizeof Temp_Buff[Other_Indx].Data);`. The `memcpy` routine is declared in `<string.h>`.

Note this use of `sizeof` relies on its operand, `Temp_Buff[Other_Indx].Data`, being an actual array of known size. If it is a pointer, you need to provide the size in some other way, such as `NumberOfElements * sizeof *Temp_Buff[Other_Indx].Data`.

Comment: Nice answer, upvoted. Could you explain what do you mean by "historical reasons"?

Comment: Follow up: if I want to copy MULTIPLE arrays, but not ALL, from one to another, I need to iterate with a memcpy for each iteration?